# AngularJS ng-include won't work for some reason

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm using the following tags for AngularJS includes:

```
<div data-ng-include src="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>
```

The footer file is in the templates directory and includes the following code

```
<footer class="primary-footer">
<div class="copyright"><small>&copy; 2015</small></div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I load the page, the footer does not load. When I check the source, it gives me a 404 error. Am I just not accessing the right directory or is this something wrong with my code?

Comment: Check the file path and compare with the console log

Comment: you gave wrong path, that is the only issue i can saw

Comment: You just need `data-ng-include="'../templates/footer.html'"` and also check whether you need the `../` in the path. Check the network in the browser developer tool for the URL that is hit to get the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<div data-ng-include src="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>
```

Use:

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>
```

Comment: what will be difference by doing this

Comment: As you can see is as easy as add the data-ng-include attribute and point it to the partial file using the data-src attribute. Notice the quotes in the path to the view, if you do not add then, Angular will treat it as an expression and try to evaluate it instead of include the template.

Comment: @pankajparkar an expression being parsed. Raw `src` attribute cannot have a valid value with extra quotes

Comment: @KirillSlatin src should also contain `'` value for template url look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 2):

Do it like - 
`<div data-ng-include="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>` 
or do it with ng-template like -
`<div ng-bind-template="'../templates/footer.html'"></div>`
both will solve your problem.